# Cannot run shell scripts in a Debian live environment that is made by debian-live-12.1.0-amd64-gnome.iso

Tags: shell-script, partition, live-usb

I created a Linux live environment similar to WinPE on USB disk A. I inserted USB disk B containing `rootfs.tar.gz`, `bzImage`, and `Burning.sh` into PC and used USB disk A to enter the live environment. However, I now realize that `Burning.sh` cannot be executed in the live environment and the following error is reported:

```
bash: ./Burning.sh： cannot execute: required file not found.
```

Content of `Burning.sh`

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash

######################################################################
#      Author: madship_xk
######################################################################

current_path=$(pwd)
#clear
    

# First, Fdisk

echo "**1************************************************************************"
echo "**2************************************************************************"


foo(){
    #clear
    echo "**3************************************************************************"
    echo "**4************************************************************************"

    ###获取第二个磁盘的信息###
    #fdisk -l | grep Disk | awk '{FS=" "} {print $2}' | sed 's/:/ /g'  > ./tmp.txt
    ls /dev/sda > ./tmp.txt
    hdstr=`awk 'NR==1 {print}' ./tmp.txt`
    echo "hdstr="${hdstr}
    rm ./tmp.txt

    echo "**5************************************************************************"
    echo "**********            1st Command: FDISK                       ***********"
    echo "**********         Plese Follow the Introduction!              ***********"
    echo "**6************************************************************************"

    fdisk ${hdstr} <<EOT 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null || exit 1
    d
    1
    d
    2
    d
    3
    d
    4
    d

    n
    p
    1

    +2G
    n
    p
    2



    w
EOT

    echo "**7************************************************************************"
    echo "**********            2nd Command: PARTX                       ***********"
    echo "**********       Please Follow the Introduction!               ***********"
    echo "**8************************************************************************"


    partx ${hdstr} 1>/dev/null

    #sleep 1
    ###判断mmcblk0###
    #if [[ ${hdstr} = '/dev/mmcblk0' ]] ; then
    #   echo "emmc exists..."
    #   hdstr=`printf "%sp" ${hdstr}`
    #   b_mmcFlag="1"
    #else
    #   echo "ssd exists..."
    #   b_mmcFlag="0"
    #fi
    #echo ${hdstr}

    sleep 1

    #clear
    echo "**9************************************************************************"
    echo "**********         3rd Command: FORMAT SDB1                    ***********"
    echo "**********       Please Follow the Introduction!               ***********"
    echo "**10************************************************************************"

    hdstr1=`printf "%s1" ${hdstr}`
    echo ${hdstr1}
    sleep 5
    mkfs.ext4 ${hdstr1} 1>/dev/null
    sleep 1

    #clear
    echo "**11************************************************************************"
    echo "**********        4th Command: FORMAT SDB2                     ***********"
    echo "**********       Please Follow the Introduction!               ***********"
    echo "**12************************************************************************"

    hdstr2=`printf "%s2" ${hdstr}`
    echo ${hdstr2}
    sleep 5
    mkfs.ext4 ${hdstr2} 1>/dev/null
    sleep 1


    #clear
    echo " "
    echo "**13************************************************************************"                                                            
    echo "**********         6th Command: MIRROR IMAGE FOR SDB1          ***********"                                       
    echo "**********         Please Follow the Introduction!             ***********"                                                                
    echo "**14************************************************************************"


    mkdir /mnt/boot
    mount ${hdastr1} /mnt/boot 1>/dev/null
    sleep 5
    grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda --force

    cat > /mnt/boot/grub/grub.cfg <<EOF 1>/dev/null || exit 1
    #Begin cfg
    set default=0
    set timeout=5

    set root=(hd0,1)

    menuentry "GNU/Linux, Test-6.4.0-rt" {
        linux /bzImage rw root=/dev/sda2
    }
EOF

    cp "${current_path}/bzImage" /mnt/boot

    umount /mnt/boot

    sleep 1

    #clear
    echo "**15************************************************************************"
    echo "**********         7th Command: MIRROR IMAGE FOR SDB2          ***********"                                                                 
    echo "**********          Please Follow the Introduction!            ***********"                                       
    echo "**16************************************************************************"                               


    sleep 2
    mount ${hdstr2} /mnt
    cp "${current_path}/rootfs.tar.gz" /mnt
    cd /mnt
    tar -vxf rootfs.tar.gz
    rm rootfs.tar.gz
    cd ~
    umount /mnt

    sync

    #clear
    echo "**17************************************************************************"
    echo "**********         7th Command: MIRROR IMAGE FOR SDB2          ***********"                                                                 
    echo "**********          Please Follow the Introduction!            ***********"                                       
    echo "**18************************************************************************"                               
}
    
jumpa(){
    echo "Please input \"BURN\" to go to start point"
    read INP
    #echo $INP
    if [[ $INP = 'BURN' ]] ; then
        echo "Going to Start POINT......"
        sleep 2
        echo 
        foo
    else
        echo 
        jumpa
    fi
}

jumpa
```

Comment: It's hard to help you. We don't know what is in drive A, nor what you mean by "small box". We also don't know how Burning sh is supposed to be executed. The error message means that there is no file named Burning.sh in the current directory. Edit your question and clarify at least the points I mentioned.

Comment: @berndbausch Is this okay?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linux Bash Shell Script Error: cannot execute: required file not found](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/721844/linux-bash-shell-script-error-cannot-execute-required-file-not-found)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by executing: `dos2unix Burning.sh`